# Update query not working - express nodejs postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

anyone can help me to find the problem ? 
I've tried to update data in users table in postgres-db. This code doesn't sent error message or anything, when I tried to check code in Postman like this (see below) I got success message, but data in database doesn't change at all.

```
router.post('/testedit/:userid', (req, res) => {
let sql = 'UPDATE users SET firstname=$1, lastname=$2, position=$3, type=$4, isadmin=$5 WHERE userid=$6'
db.query(sql, [req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname, req.body.position, req.body.type, req.body.isadmin, req.params.userid], (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.json({
    message: 'update success'
  })
})
```

})

Comment: What is the value of $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 and $6?

Comment: What is PostgreSQL telling to you? You could check on query body with `console.log(data)`

Comment: Your code looks right, what are you expecting? If you do a select in database  you will see the data updated.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the code that COMMITs the transaction.  If the UPDATE is not committed then it will not last after/outside the session it was done in.